# How to rename files using HttpUtility.UrlEncode method in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of html files that I need to rename with url encoding before I upload them to the server. I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -Filter *.html | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("*.html",[Web.Httputility]::UrlEncode("*.html")) }
```

But that doesn't apply the encoding, can this be even done somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic way to do it, [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548778/4172124):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -Filter *.html -File) |
foreach { ren $_.fullname ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_))}
```

Originally I had written it without the `()` around the `Get-ChildItem`, but found it was still reading directory information while the rename had already renamed the first item. Then the rename reencoded the first item a second time, thus making it a bit munged up.

Here's a cleaner version that handles the files first and then folders:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -Filter *.html -File
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -Filter *.html -Directory
$files | foreach { ren $_.fullname ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_))}
$folders | foreach { ren $_.fullname ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_))}
```

Comment: This also adds path to the filenames, how can i avoid that?

Comment: @ BoogaRoo Your solution doesn't work , because top folder gets renamed and therefor path to the files inside it will change and so they can't be found any more.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention folders in my original question

Comment: @PeterPavelka Alright, I think the updated cleaner version suits your situation and also avoids accidentally renaming folders first. If this is not the case, it may  help to update the question with folder structure and additional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answers i did this to make it work

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse -Filter *.html) |
foreach { ren $_.fullName ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Name))} | Out-Null

Get-ChildItem -Path c:\temp\ -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } |
 foreach { ren $_.fullName ([uri]::EscapeDataString($_.Name))}
```

First I had to do only files and then folders, because when top folder gets renamed, then the path to files inside it doesn't exist any more.